# Node.js+Mongodb how to get the attribute value from Json format?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I built the server with Node.js and use a MongoDB database. I don't know how to get the attribute value from a result returned by database. The format is JSON and the code is:

```
 exports.queryExams = function(db, data, callback) {
        var exams = db.collection("exams");
        var stream = exams.find(data).stream();
        stream.on("data", function(item) {
            callback(item);
        });

    app.post("/showExam", urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {

            var examName = req.body.examName;

            console.log(examName);

            var data = {examName:examName};

            MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
                assert.equal(null, err);
                console.log("Connected correctly to server");
                examDao.queryExams(db, data, function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    db.close();
                });
            });
        });
```

**Example Data**:

```
{ _id: 561cc05ba9659d040569ffdf,
  examName: 'Test1',
  userName: 'Jack',
  examId: 3,
  array: 
   [ { examsId: 1, databaseId: 146 },
     { examsId: 2, databaseId: 1168 },
     { examsId: 3, databaseId: 1169 },
     { examsId: 4, databaseId: 147 },
     { examsId: 5, databaseId: 145 } ] }
```

How can I get the attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

What attribute are you talking about?

If you just want to access one of the properties of the result object, you can access them in a dot-style syntax:

```
console.log(result.examName);
```

Alternatively access the properties in a dictionary-syntax

```
console.log(result["examName"]);
```

Arrays can be looped:

```
for(var i in result["array"]) {
    console.log(result["array"][i]["examsId"];
}
```

---

*As a sidenote: I would try to not open a MongoDB connection everytime you process a request but rather try to open the MongoDB connection once and recycle/reuse it. In the best case by using the connection pooling function of MongoDB's NodeJS connector.*